# Hashing multiple columns of spark dataframe

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark

I need to hash specific columns of spark dataframe. Some columns have specific datatype which are basically the extensions of standard spark's DataType class. The problem is because for some reason in *when* case some conditions don't work as expected.

As a hash table I have a map. Let's call it tableConfig:

```scala
val tableConfig = Map("a" -> "KEEP", "b" -> "HASH", "c" -> "KEEP", "d" -> "HASH", "e" -> "KEEP")
```

The salt variable is used to concatenate with column:

```scala
val salt = "abc"
```

The function for hashing looks like this:

```scala
def hashColumns(tableConfig: Map[String, String], salt: String, df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

    val removedColumns = tableConfig.filter(_._2 == "REMOVE").keys.toList
    val hashedColumns = tableConfig.filter(_._2 == "HASH").keys.toList

    val cleanedDF = df.drop(removedColumns: _ *)

    val colTypes = cleanedDF.dtypes.toMap

    def typeFromString(s: String): DataType = s match {
      case "StringType" => StringType
      case "BooleanType" => BooleanType
      case "IntegerType" => IntegerType
      case "DateType" => DateType
      case "ShortType" => ShortType
      case "DecimalType(15,7)" => DecimalType(15,7)
      case "DecimalType(18,2)" => DecimalType(18,2)
      case "DecimalType(11,7)" => DecimalType(11,7)
      case "DecimalType(17,2)" => DecimalType(17,2)
      case "DecimalType(38,2)" => DecimalType(38,2)
      case _ => throw new TypeNotPresentException(
        "Please check types in the dataframe. The following column type is missing: ".concat(s), null
      )
    }

    val getType = colTypes.map{case (k, _) => (k, typeFromString(colTypes(k)))}

    val hashedDF = cleanedDF.columns.foldLeft(cleanedDF) {
      (memoDF, colName) =>
        memoDF.withColumn(
          colName,
          when(col(colName).isin(hashedColumns: _*) && col(colName).isNull, null).
            when(col(colName).isin(hashedColumns: _*) && col(colName).isNotNull,
              sha2(concat(col(colName), lit(salt)), 256)).otherwise(col(colName)
            )
        )
    }

    hashedDF
  }
```

I am getting error regarding to specific column. Namely the error is the following:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`c` IN ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e'))' due to data type mismatch: Arguments must be same type but were: boolean != string;;

*Column names are changed.*

My search didn't give any clear explanation why isin or isNull functions don't work as expected. Also I follow specific style of implementation and want to avoid the following approaches:

1) No UDFs. They are painful for me.

2) No for loops over spark dataframe columns. The data could contain more than billion samples and it's going to be a headache in terms of performance.

Comment: as the error says it seems to be a mismatch between `columns` and hashedColumns. But, before that you must fix your condition, this `col(colName).isin(hashedColumns: _*) && col(colName).isNull` is never true since `col(colName)` can't be null and at the same time has one the values: `['a', 'b', 'c', etc]`. Instead of `isin` you probably need to use [array_contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_contains)

Comment: In Addition to @AlexandrosBiratsis's comment, you should transform some columns to their String representation, based on their DataType (try using your ``getType`` function)

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis thanks! I will check. But I am not sure that it would be possible to use array_contains expression along with boolean conditions.

Comment: @baitmbarek unfortunately casting doesn't help, just left helping code in the function.

Comment: You should not simply cast your columns but rather transform them to some String **representation**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the first FIX should be to remove the condition `col(colName).isin(hashedColumns: _*) && col(colName).isNull` since this check will be always *false*.

As for the error, it is because of the mismatch between value type of `col(colName)` and `hashedColumns`. The value of `hashedColumns` is always a string therefore `col(colName)` should be a string as well but in your case it seems to be a `Boolean`.

The last issue that I see here it has to do with the logic of the `foldLeft`. If I understood correctly what you want to achieve is to go through the columns and apply `sha2` for those that exist in `hashedColumns`. To achieve that you must change your code to:

```scala
// 1st change: Convert each element of hashedColumns from String to Spark col
val hashArray = hashedColumns.map(lit(_))

val hashedDF = cleanedDF.columns.foldLeft(cleanedDF) {
  (memoDF, colName) =>
    memoDF.withColumn(
      colName,

      // 2nd.change: check if colName is in "a", "b", "c", "d" etc, if so apply sha2 otherwise leave the value as it is
      when(col(colName).isNotNull && array_contains(array(hashArray:_*), lit(colName)) ,
        sha2(concat(col(colName), lit(salt)), 256)
      )
    )
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Iterating through all the columns via `foldLeft` wouldn't be efficient and adds extra overhead, even more when you have large number of columns (see discussion with @baitmbarek below) I added one more approach instead of `foldLeft` using single select. In the next code `when` is applied only for the `hashedColumns`. We separate the columns into nonHashedCols and transformedCols then we concatenate the list and pass it to the `select`:

```scala
val transformedCols = hashedColumns.map{ c =>
  when(col(c).isNotNull , sha2(concat(col(c), lit(salt)), 256)).as(c)
}

val nonHashedCols = (cleanedDF.columns.toSet -- hashedColumns.toSet).map(col(_)).toList

cleanedDF.select((nonHashedCols ++ transformedCols):_*)
```

Comment: That should be enough to fix the problem, but be careful when folding on columns. It's not performant when dealing with lots of them.

Comment: you are right @baitmbarek and it would be probably a better solution to generate the final df based on `hashedColumns` only and not all the columns.
 Thank you for pointing out that

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis it's amazing! Thank you so much! I totally forgot (very often jump between Scala and Python) that it's possible to define variable as transformedCols in your code. Already accepted your answer. I will update my post mentioning your solution very soon.

Comment: yes @memu the provided functionality of the Column class is very rich and flexible hence you can use it in many ways. The dynamic select as shown above is a commonly suggested case

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted a solution on behalf of the question author, to move it from the question to the answer section)*.

@AlexandrosBiratsis gave very good solution in terms of performance and elegant implementation. So the hashColumns function will look like this:

```scala
def hashColumns(tableConfig: Map[String, String], salt: String, df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

    val removedCols = tableConfig.filter(_._2 == "REMOVE").keys.toList
    val hashedCols = tableConfig.filter(_._2 == "HASH").keys.toList

    val cleanedDF = df.drop(removedCols: _ *)

    val transformedCols = hashedCols.map{ c =>
      when(col(c).isNotNull , sha2(concat(col(c), lit(salt)), 256)).as(c)
    }
    val nonHashedCols = (cleanedDF.columns.toSet -- hashedCols.toSet).map(col(_)).toList
    val hashedDF = cleanedDF.select((nonHashedCols ++ transformedCols):_*)

    hashedDF
  }
```